# WCF NetTcpBinding channel caching

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

We have a service that makes NetTcp calls to other services on different servers. I'm trying to optimize it by caching the ChannelFactories, and by increasing maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint.

I have been using GOOGLE.COM (great website, by the way. Check it out if you haven't heard of them) to try to understand how the channel caching works, and I don't think I have it correct.

Reusing the channel factory - good idea.
Caching channels myself - bad idea. Wcf already does this, as long as all of your channels are created from the same factory. - is that right? If you create a new factory each time, it's not cached?

```
    // factory initialization
    var address = "net.tcp://something:8888/testservices";
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>("configname", new EndpointAddress(address));

    // do stuff
    var client = factory.CreateChannel(); // you can also pass an address here. how does that effect channel caching?
```

So that handles the factory stuff. Now, I want to increase maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint, which is achieved via a custom binding. The thing that's not clear there is the GroupName. I can't specify distinct group names in configuration because I'm looking up the URL at runtime. Thus, all channel factories are going to have the same default group name. Are they going to share the same pool, does each factory have it's own?

In the end, I would like to create the custom binding in configuration, then create/cache multiple channel factories as needed, and use them to establish channels. And, I need to increase the maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint per endpoint. I may be calling the same service on 20 different machines, and I want up to 50 cached channels for each. Does the code above achieve that?

Thank you for your help. If there is a link that covers this, please forward. I haven't been able to find it.